# Stationary points of $ \ln(x + 1)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to find the stationary points of $f(x) =\ln(x + 1)$.

When I differentiate, I get $f'(x) =\dfrac{1}{ (x + 1)}.$

I then set that to zero and end up getting $1 = 0$?

I'm not sure what this means and I don't know what to do at this point.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Considering that the graph of ln(1+x) is always increasing, the fact that you found no solutions to f'(x) = 0 should make sense.

Comment: none. there is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the domain of $f(x)= \ln(x+1)$ is $(-1, \infty)$. Furthermore, for all $x\in \mathbb R$, $\dfrac 1{x+1} \neq 0$.

That means that $f(x)$ has no minimum/maximum on the domain on which $\log(x+1)$ is defined.

To see this for yourself, graph $f(x) = \ln(x+1)$:

[image]

$f(x)$ is strictly increasing on the domain of definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your differentiation is correct, and there is no solution for 
$$\frac{1}{1+x}=0,$$
for any $x$. What does this tell us about the graph of $f(x)=\ln(x+1)$? Well, since, mathematically, we cannot find any stationary points, it's worth looking at the graph of the function. Put the function into a graphics calculator, or type it into the input bar [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/). What we can see is that there seems to be no point at which the gradient of the function is zero, and therefore $\ln(x+1)$ does not have any stationary points.

As an interesting aside note, we know that 
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$$
and also that
$$e^x\neq 0 \ \ \ \text{for any} \ x$$
and hence $f(x)=e^x$ does not have any stationary points. Since $\ln(x)$ is the inverse function of $e^x$, we have an explanation as to why $ln(c+1)$ has no stationary points.